# What is the record for combined (Test, ODI & T20) most player of the series award?

Tags: cricket, trivia, records, awards

Which are the players who won most Man of the Series awards in international cricket including Test, ODI & T20.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Sachin Tendulkar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sachin_Tendulkar) holds the record for combined (Test, ODI & T20) most player of the series awards in international cricket with ***20***.

From [stats.espncricinfo](http://stats.espncricinfo.com/nclod/content/records/283467.html) "Most player-of-the-series awards":

[image: record]

Disclaimer at the end reads:

> Series awards have not always been a regular feature in internationals and the list may not be complete for matches prior to the 1980s

Sachin also holds the record for combined [most player of the match awards](http://stats.espncricinfo.com/icc-odi/content/records/283470.html) with ***76***.